# MySQL select данных и update одного поля на эти данные

Tags: mysql, запрос, select, update

У меня есть SELECT запрос, которым я получаю данные и с ними работаю в PHP:

```sql
SELECT addr, appid, failedquery 
FROM servers 
WHERE lastupdate+900 < 'текущее время' 
  AND isupdating = 0 
ORDER BY lastupdate LIMIT 10;
```

И мне нужно в этих выбранных данных изменить поле `isupdating` на 1, то есть что сервера находятся на обновлении. Я бы мог конечно сделать в самом php перебор этих данных и по уникальному полю делать:

```sql
UPDATE servers 
SET isupdating = 1 
WHERE addr = 'addr из select запроса'
```

и так на каждую строчку. Но если будет LIMIT не 10, а скажем 10000 - и на каждую строку самому из PHP кидать 10000 запросов UPDATE не очень хорошо.

Так вот вопрос, могу ли я получить данные SELECT'ом и тут же при этом обновить одно поле во всех этих выбранных данных в одном запросе? Наверняка есть какие-то ухищрения.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT addr, appid, failedquery 
FROM servers
WHERE isupdating = 0
  AND lastupdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 900 SECOND;
```

и соответственно

```
UPDATE servers
SET isupdating = 1
WHERE isupdating = 0
  AND lastupdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 900 SECOND;
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 900 SECOND` - это константа, которая вычислится один раз (причём ещё на этапе построения плана выполнения), и запрос может использовать индекс по полю `lastupdate`. Тогда как показанный в тексте вопроса запрос индекс использовать не может, и выполнит полный скан таблицы, что очевидно будет медленнее.

---

> могу ли я получить данные SELECT'ом и тут же при этом обновить одно поле во всех этих выбранных данных в одном запросе?

Нет.

Comment: Я пытался сделать именно так, то есть селектить с условием и потом апдейтить с тем же условием, но в таком случае если навесить сверху LIMIT и ORDER - то эти два запроса меняют разные данные. SELECT выбирает одно, а UPDATE обновляет совсем другое, хотя, повторюсь, условия в WHERE одинаковые. Похоже, что придётся всё-таки делать обновление вручную из PHP для каждого сервера, очень жаль.

Comment: @Fragrus `LIMIT`, если нужна определённость и повторяемость, должен сопровождаться `ORDER BY`, причём по выражению, по которому записи уникальны.